# Best sequence of using Vacuum, optimize, fsck repair and refresh commands on delta tables

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, spark-streaming, data-warehouse, delta-lake

i have a delta table whose size will increase gradually. now we have around 15 million rows while running vacuum command on that table i am getting the below error.

> ERROR: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 491.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.4 in stage 481.0 (TID 4116) (10.154.64.26 executor 7): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 7 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 177186 ms

and also wanted to know the best order of using

```
VACUUM table RETAIN 168 HOURS 

optimize table;

fsck repair table table;

REFRESH table table;
```

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *crore*, and also, don't put the same text more than once into your question.

Comment: `ExecutorLostFailure`s are really hard to diagnose unless you provide enough information and are usually a side effect of some other memory-related issues. There had to be more information earlier in the logs to pinpoint the root cause of the issue.